# Json return issue

Tags: json, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I just finished upgrading VS 2010, MVC 2, jQuery 1.7 app to VS 2012, MVC 5 and jQuery 1.10.

The app uses MicrosoftAjax.js and MicrosoftMvcAjax.js.

I am posting a form and the action is returning a json result. For this i am getting the following error on the client side:

```
TypeError: context.get_data is not a function
var json = context.get_data();

TypeError: context.get_object is not a function 
var json = context.get_object().get_data();
```

Please note that original code was using context.get_data(). After the error i changed it to context.get_object().get_data().

I have also tried encoding the json result as following but this is still resulting in the same error:

```
public JsonResult AddJsonUtf8Encoding(JsonResult result)
        {
            result.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            result.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
            return result;
        }
```

javascript on page:

```
var MvcTopBarLogin = 
{
    beginAjaxForm: function () {
        $('#msgboxSignInTopBar').removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('Validating....').fadeIn(1000);
    },
    successAjaxForm: function (context) {
        **var json = context.get_object().get_data();**
        //var json = context.get_data();
        var data = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(json);
        if (data.IsError) {
            if (data.IsGone) {
                window.location.href = data.RedirectUrl;
            }
            else {
                $('#msgboxSignInTopBar').fadeTo(200, 0.1, function () {
                    $(this).html(data.Message).addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900, 1).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
                });
            }
        }
        else {
            if (data.RedirectUrl == "")
                window.location.reload();
            else
                window.location.href = data.RedirectUrl;
        }
    }    
}
```

html:

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm(ActionNames.ValidateUser,
                ControllerNames.Account, 
                new { Area = "" },
               new AjaxOptions
               {
                   HttpMethod = "Post",
                   OnBegin = "MvcTopBarLogin.beginAjaxForm",
                   OnSuccess = "MvcTopBarLogin.successAjaxForm"
               }, new { id = "loginForm" }))
            { %>

        <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
        <%= Html.HiddenFor(x => x.RawUrl) %>



        <div id="signIn">
            <input type="image" src="<%= Url.Image("/Structure/Buttons/btn_signIn_topBar.gif") %>" class="ntptEventTag" ntptEventTag="TopBox-MVC-Login" />
        </div>
        <div id="login_box">
            <label for="Password" class="overlabel">
                Password</label>
            <%= Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Password, new { @class = "textBox swap_value", tabIndex = 2 })%>
        </div>
        <div id="login_box">
            <label for="Username" class="overlabel">
                Username</label>
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Username, new { @class = "textBox swap_value", tabIndex = 1 })%>
        </div>
    <%
        } %>
```

Thanks for looking.

Comment: I have also checked "context.get_response().get_object();" and this resulted in the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working with encoding:

```
var MvcTopBarLogin = 
{
    beginAjaxForm: function () {
        $('#msgboxSignInTopBar').removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('Validating....').fadeIn(1000);
    },
    successAjaxForm: function (context) {
        //var json = context.get_object().get_data();
        //var json = context.get_data();
        //var json = context.get_response().get_object().get_data();
        var data = context; //Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(json);

        if (data.IsError) {
            if (data.IsGone) {
                window.location.href = data.RedirectUrl;
            }
            else {
                $('#msgboxSignInTopBar').fadeTo(200, 0.1, function () {
                    $(this).html(data.Message).addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900, 1).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
                });
            }
        }
        else {
            if (data.RedirectUrl == "")
                window.location.reload();
            else
                window.location.href = data.RedirectUrl;
        }
    }    
};
```